# Restrict multiple login of users

Tags: java

I have to restrict multiple logins of users from different place.
For this I have written code as:

```
ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
HashMap logInMap = null;
if (context.getAttribute("logInMap") != null) {
  logInMap = (HashMap) context.getAttribute("logInMap");
  if (logInMap .containsValue(session.getId())) {
    System.out.println("duplicatesession");
    // done something...
  }else if ( logInMap.get(loginId) != null && !logInMap.get(loginId).equals(session.getId()) ) {
    System.out.println("already Logged In");
    //done something...
  }
} else {
  logInMap = new HashMap();
}
logInMap.put(loginId, session.getId());
context.setAttribute("loginMap",logInMap);
```

But in above code for each request a new `HashMap` is getting generated.
If I declare `HashMap` as static then problem is occurred while I am directly closing the browser. 
It would be greatly appreciated if any one could help with this problem.
If the solution is in Spring that would be great.

Comment: According to your code your are storing the `HashMap` in `ServletContext` and not generating it each time. You shouldn't declare it as static. What "problem is occurred"? The spring way is [spring security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) it's probably an overkill for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood issue correctly, you want to restrict user login only one at a time.

Use case 1 : logout old login once user login from another place

Solution : in login table, keep a column in user_credentials table, **is_loggedIn**, set its value to "True" on successful login and set to false after "logout". 
   while checking login credentials every time check, if **is_loggedIn** is set to true, call log out internally, to remove the previous user and then call login again.

Use Case 2 : Don't allow user to login, until its logged out from previous state

Solution : Refering to above solution of having a column in user_login credentials table, throw error message "logout from previous device" if **is_loggedIn** is set true.

Comment: Use case 1  is suitable for me, but I have only view authorization on database. I need to do it without interact with database.